# Access Query Expression From Combo Box Data Returns Integer Instead of Text Data (Design View)

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba

I am creating a new Field for a Query table, but when I try to concatenate two columns I get returned an Index value instead of the actual text from the column. NOTE: This is for Design View and not VBA editor. Also the Query of a Linked Table from a Sharepoint List.

I have tried using .Value, .Text, .Column(1), but all these operators only work in the VBA editor. The Access Query Design View doesn't recognize these operators. How do I modify my expression below to return the text value of the combobox instead of the index of the value?

```
newField: [TableName].[SchoolName] & " , " & [TableName].[Professor]
```

The Query table's newField now instead returns the value:

"1 , Dr. Lawson" instead of "University of Washington , Dr. Lawson"

Comment: This is because the actual value in field is the ID, not the text that is displayed. This is why I recommend not building lookup field in table, especially when alias is involved. I prefer to see the actual value stored. JOIN tables in query to retrieve related info.

Comment: @HansUp Thanks. I didn't think of that problem. The Linked Table is pulling from a Sharepoint List. So you're saying that the actual value of SchoolName even from the Linked Table is actually the Index value of the combo box and not the stored text value? Can you elaborate on the idea to "JOIN tables in query to retrieve the data"? I'm trying to concatenate two column fields into one from the same linked table, not from multiple different tables. How would JOINing two tables help with this?